# Custom springboot autoconfiguration not detecting beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I developed a custom Spring Boot autoconfiguration to ease working with a proprietary messaging library.

The main autoconfiguration class is essentially as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({LibServer.class, LibClient.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties(LibProperties.class)
public class LibAutoConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    LibProperties props;

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(LibServer.class)
    public LibServer lbServ() {
        // create and configure a server object
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(LibClient.class)
    public LibClient lbClient() {
        //create and configure a client object
    }
}
```

It seems however that the conditional annotation is not detecting beans declared in the main `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class.

It only detects beans declared in separate `@Configuration` annotated classes.

That is to say if I place two `@Bean` annotated methods returning a `LibServer` and a `LibClient` object in the main class I end up with two `LibServer` and two `LibClient` objects (the autoconfigured ones and the explicitly declared ones) in the context.

Native spring boot autoconfigurations (such as `DataSource` one) can instead detect beans declared in the main class too (such as a `@Bean` annotated `jdbcTemplate` method).

How do I get proper bean detection even for beans declared in the main class?

**Edit**

A complete multimodule maven project exhibiting the behaviour is at https://github.com/AlexFalappa/spring-boot-testcase

Comment: What does your _main class_ look like and how do you run your app?

Comment: You're not importing your `LibAutoConfiguration` yourself, do you? Auto-configuration classes _must_ be defined in `spring.factories` and not loaded directly. This is important in this case as we need to process all user configuration first and then check if we have to create those beans.

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll: my custom autoconfiguration is in a maven module which do contain the relevant `spring.factories` file and also acts as a starter module by declaring a dependency on the proprietary messaging lib. The application is in a different maven module which depends on the former.

Comment: @Morfic: The main class is that of a normal spring boot app annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You're not importing your LibAutoConfiguration yourself, do you?

This was the hint: your main class is in a parent package from your auto-configuration class. So you're actually importing the `@Configuration` yourself through component scan. It turns out that when you process that class (via an explicit import rather than via auto-configuration), no beans have been created yet so it does create them. Your application class is processed later and create those beans as well.

If you move the definition somewhere else, it *might* work (as you have figured out yourself with `LibConfig`) but that's not deterministic.

`TL;DR` make sure that your auto-configuration code is in a separate space and is *not* the target of component scan. I have moved your `DemoLibboApplication` to the `demo` package and it worked as expected.

Comment: That was it. Maybe this is worth pointing out in the _Creating your own auto-configuration_ sectionin the Spring Boot docs?

Comment: Alright, I've created [#5404](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5404)

Comment: What is the point of annotating auto-configuration classes with `@Configuration` if those classes are not intended to be scanned? If this is purely informational, it would certainly reduce confusion to make them `@AutoConfiguration` which are NOT registered when on the classpath and throw exception if not registered in spring.factories.

Comment: `@Configuration` is the stereotype for a component that registers bean definition using `@Bean` factory methods. This is unrelated to classpath scanning although this is is a side effect if you point component scan to it. The context will create a proxy for the class so that if you call other factory bean methods internally for explicit dependency injection, you have the guarantee to retrieve a bean that matches the defined scope. We introduced recently a `proxyBeanMethods` attribute to turn that off.

Comment: Your `@AutoConfiguration` suggestion has the opposite problem (ignoring the fact that the above wouldn't work). If you forget to register it in spring.factories, then it's not an auto-configuration. It's far worse than the current situation IMO.

Answer (score 8):

If you set the log level on debug in you `application.properties` (`logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG`), you will notice that Spring will detect both definitions. However you will also see that [the order in which this happens may not be what you expected](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-bean-conditions), because it instantiate beans from the library configuration first, and AFTERWARDS from your *main class* , and thus you get 2 instances (stripped timestamps to make it friendlier):

**Bean definitions**

```
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader : Registering bean definition for @Bean method af.spring.boot.libbo.LibAutoConfiguration.lbServ()
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'autoConfigurationReport'
a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader : Registering bean definition for @Bean method af.spring.boot.libbo.LibAutoConfiguration.lbClient()
a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader : Registering bean definition for @Bean method af.DemoLibboApplication.libServ()
a.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader : Registering bean definition for @Bean method af.DemoLibboApplication.libClient()
```

**Bean instantiation**

```
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'lbServ'
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'lbServ'
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'libAutoConfiguration'
Autoconfiguring LibServer
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Eagerly caching bean 'lbServ' to allow for resolving potential circular references
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'lbServ'
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'lbClient'
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'lbClient'
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'libAutoConfiguration'
Autoconfiguring LibClient
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Eagerly caching bean 'lbClient' to allow for resolving potential circular references
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'lbClient'
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lib.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES'
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor'
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.store'
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'libServ'
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'libServ'
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'demoLibboApplication'
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Eagerly caching bean 'libServ' to allow for resolving potential circular references
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'libServ'
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'libClient'
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Creating instance of bean 'libClient'
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'demoLibboApplication'
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Eagerly caching bean 'libClient' to allow for resolving potential circular references
o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Finished creating instance of bean 'libClient'
```

You can also see in the `AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT` that in your current implementation when the conditionals in the `LibAutoConfiguration` are evaluated, they match and normally it creates the beans:

```
Positive matches:
-----------------
...
LibAutoConfiguration#lbClient matched
  - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: af.libbo.LibClient; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

LibAutoConfiguration#lbServ matched
  - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: af.libbo.LibServer; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)
...
```

However, if you add the same condition to your *main class*, you'll see that it will create the beans according to the definitions in `LibAutoConfiguration`, and when trying to create those for `DemoLibboApplication`, it will actually find the previously created beans and skip the instantiation:

```
Negative matches:
-----------------
...
DemoLibboApplication#libClient did not match
  - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: af.libbo.LibServer; SearchStrategy: all) found the following [lbServ] (OnBeanCondition)

DemoLibboApplication#libServ did not match
  - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: af.libbo.LibServer; SearchStrategy: all) found the following [lbServ] (OnBeanCondition)
...
```